# Premake cannot find lua script in my repo (exact same repo works on my mainpc)

Tags: python, lua, visual-studio-2017, premake

[I have a github repo which has an implementation of premake that works on my main PC, but not on my laptop.](https://github.com/LarssonMartin1998/CustomFrameworkForSFML2.4.2)

When I run my python script to generate the project files I get the error: "No Premake script (premake5.lua) found!"

So I decided to follow premakes tutorial for writing your first script on my laptop and created a directory that contains four files: premake5.exe, premake5.lua, hello.c and generate_project_files.py. But it still doesn't work, I recieve the same error. You can see the files below. I also added a for loop which prints all the files in the directory. When the script runs, after saying that premake5.lua is not found, it lists all the files(including premake5.lua).

python script:

```
import os
import subprocess

premake_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "\\"

args = [
        premake_dir + "premake5.exe",
        "vs2017",
        "--file=" + premake_dir + "premake5.lua"
        ]

subprocess.run(args)

for file in os.listdir(premake_dir):
    print(file)
```

lua script:

```
-- premake5.lua
workspace "HelloWorld"
   configurations { "Debug", "Release" }

project "HelloWorld"
   kind "ConsoleApp"
   language "C"
   targetdir "bin/%{cfg.buildcfg}"

   files { "**.h", "**.c" }

   filter "configurations:Debug"
      defines { "DEBUG" }
      symbols "On"

   filter "configurations:Release"
      defines { "NDEBUG" }
      optimize "On"
```

I have no idea how to solve this problem as I have never encountered it before, and after searching for a fix i've found nothing even remotely close. Please share if you've ever encountered anything similar or know a fix.

Comment: What happens if you run that same command manually from the command line? On the machine where it doesn't work, are there any spaces in the path to `premake_dir`?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to the difference between LUA_PATH/LUA_CPATH on your main PC versus this other one. Compare package.path and package.cpath in both Lua environments. Ensure that its in path.